# hide id using jquery but the input is an array

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery code I have been using for some time however today I ran into a roadblock - this roadblock comes in the form of an array input.

```
<div id="primary">   //oopse this one contains the survey info
<input type="radio" name="quest[]" value="yes">   //was typing fast didnt realize i typed checkbox meant radio
<input type="radio" name="quest[]" value="no">
</div>
<div id="idnum">   // this one shows only if yes is selected
blah blah blah
</div>
```

So the inputs are sending to query[]
the logical thing to me says to not use an array - however this is not an option.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#quest[] selected").change(function (e) {
      if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {   //if query[] = Yes then run following
        $("#idnum").hide();            //hide div id=idnum
      }
      else {     //if it no longer shows yes then run following
        $("#idnum").show();    //show div id=idnum
          }     
    });
  });
```

array[] has other values under this array for other questions also
how do I fix this to focus on a specific input in the array - each div has a different id and I do have the ability to find the array[number] if need be.

sorry fixed some things and annotated a little

I dont know if it is possible but is it possible to find the  with a value of "Yes" that is listed in a specific

Comment: `quest[]` is not a value of an ID attribute, right?

Comment: no quest[] is the value of the input from the radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kpxQt/1/)

```
// to grab them by name starting with "quest[" the rest will be dynamic you said
$('[name^="quest["]').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('value') === 'yes') {
        $(this).closest('div').hide();
    }
});
```

If I understand the question correctly, and you are trying to hide the nearest parent `<div>` and hide it, if they select YES.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you just need something like:

```
$("[name^=quest][value=yes]").change(function () {
   $("#idnum").toggle();
});
```

..but I have many questions.  Why would you allow them to check "yes" and "no" at the same time?

Comment: that was an accident - i meant to do radio - I have annotated and fixed errors

Answer (score 0):

using # is for id's quest[] is the name

the css selector for that would be

```
$('[name="quest[]"]')
```

That said I am unsure what you are trying to do

Finding the checked quest[]/s would be:-

```
$('[name="quest[]"]').find(':checked')
```